# Appmaker migration from Drive table to Cloud SQL queries

Tags: google-app-maker

We already have 2 Appmaker Apps **LIVE** in our domain, As Drive table are deprecated now we want to migrate from Drive table to Cloud SQL, now in doing so I have following queries,

1. Do we need to follow any further steps to do data migration from Drive table data to Cloud SQL Data? Or it will happen automatically?
2. Do we need to make any code changes in our existing App? Or the same code will work with Cloud SQL as data source?

I have gone through release document note [here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/release-notes), but it does not mention answers to above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no chance to play with it a lot, but I'll share my understanding of the topic.

1. Before proceeding with the migration I would highly recommend to [make backups](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export) of all important deployments.
2. `App Settings -> Upgrade to Google Cloud SQL` will upgrade your models and your personal Preview deployment, but it will not affect Preview deployments of other app developers. App Maker will try to adjust SQL specific fields settings basing on data in your Preview database (for example strings' lengths).
3. Particular deployment's data will be migrated on the first publish after the migration. On this step App Maker will analyze deployment's data and try to make fields adjustments (for instance increase strings lengths).

I hope to see more detailed official docs on this topic soon...

Comment: Okay Pavel. This helps, please keep us posted on the detailed official docs